# When put a "padding" property on a child element in percentage, button doesn't stretch and text falls out of the container

Tags: css, sass, padding

Here is an example

```
    <button style="min-width: 150px; height: 63px;">
        <div style="padding-left: 70%;">something</div>
    </button>
```

I tried different options with "width" property for both(child and parent elemetns), but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is based on the container.

Your container is `150px` wide, your padding is `(150 - left & right padding - left & right border width) * 0.7`.

Let's say that the button itself has no padding and border, `150 * 0.7 = 105`.

Adding to it the size of the content "something" (let's say `65px`), it overflows (`105 + 65 = 170 > 150)`.

Imagine the button width increases and become `170px`, it would be the same problem, the padding change to `170 * 0.7 = 119px`, so the new button width would be `119 + 65px = 184px`, etc.

I suggest you to use an other [unit of measure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

If you need a padding depending on the container width, you can use percentage but with reasonable values : decrease the padding, increase the width, or set a % width to your div (but in this case the text "something" will still overflow), etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to set padding for a child element depending on a width of the parent element. What is the best unit for implementing this?

Comment: Then % is the way, but you need reasonable values. 70% of 150px is a lot and leaves little space for the content. You can decrease the div padding or increase the button width

Comment: What if my text inside the div can be displayed in different languages. And depending on the language, button width can be bigger or smaller. I mean that I do not know the exact width of the button, because the same text in several languages is different...

Comment: It's starting to be too specific, I would recommand to set the padding with an absolute unit as `px` because I don't imagine a case why you would need a padding depending on the text length. Maybe something like `width: 100%;max-width: 500px;` on the button, but I can't tell